# Strange pop up when booting Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Every time I start my computer (Windows 8.1) a document that I scanned pops up upside down before I even get to the login screen.  If I move my cursor over it, it goes away.  Has anyone ever seen this happen or know how to fix it?

Comment: Weird. Can you record a video of it and post it somewhere? (assuming the document isn't terribly confidential)

Comment: Check for startup items. Better to use **autoruns** from sysinternals

Comment: And please run a virus scan. That might be some malware doing so.